# php & .net security issue?

Tags: php, asp.net

I have an old .net application which also contains a vbuletin forum in php.

I have created a **custom handler** to protect access to some files (*.doc etc) for non-autheticated users in .net app. The main problem is that now, **all vbulletin users can no longer access these files.**

Is there any setting I can do in order to make those files accessible for these php users? Because, all the requests are going trough my custom handler...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For this specic case I've done a custom solution:

- I've checked in the handler **if the request comes from a php url** and **if this url contains my host**, so I know it comes from the forum hosted on our site.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options that you can go with here.

1. If you can set a cookie for the users, regardless of PHP or .NET, then you could modify your handler to serve content based on the existence of the cookie, or similar.  (You could use encrypted user value or other item if you need more than just a "yes/no"
2. You could move the two applications into two different silos/virtual directories.  Public docs in one location for PHPBB and another for the .NET application
3. You could modify your handler to only handle certain folders/sub-folder within the structure which might allow you to get around.

Comment: Thanks Michel. Can you please give me an example for point 3? It sounds very interesting!